# How to change the format of a 13 digit number to a date in R

Tags: r, date, format

I imported a dataset into R and one of the variables is a date but it is showing as a 13 digit number as such 1269576000000.
How can I change this number into a date? I am not sure what the format should be like but i'm guessing that this number also contains information about time (hours, minutes, seconds).
Is there any code to directly change the format of this variable in R?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the actual date and timezone that number corresponds to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most common form would be the number of seconds from Jan 1, 1970, at least that is what the POSIX standard has been. Unlike Simon0101, I think you should be using `as.POSIXct`, because you will generally be wanting to stick such results in dataframes and POSIXlt objects get messed up in that environment. You apparently are being given the time in the number of milliseconds however:

```
> as.POSIXct(1269576000000, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "42201-04-06 17:00:00 PDT"       # not a sensible result
> as.POSIXct(1269576000000/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2010-03-26 05:00:00 PDT"
```

So it was neither the number of fractional days nor seconds but rather the number of milliseconds since the origin.

Comment: Please could you provide an example of `POSIXlt` objects getting messed by being stuck in a data.frame?

Comment: Thanks a lot DWin, it worked for some of my variables however when i try it on the other it gives me the following error: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(X$Y, 1000) :
  / not meaningful for factors.
What should i do in this case?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you wrap `as.numeric(as.character(.)) areung that column it should work. You will probably get some NA values because during input what you thought was a numeric value got read in (probably by one of the `read.*` functions) as a character/factor variable.

Comment: @SimonO101: At the moment it appears that the earlier behavior has been sidestepped or finessed by the fact that the `data.frame` function now coerces POSIXlt variables to POSIXct variables. I think R Core may have gotten tired of the obscure bugs and misinterpretations that arose from have things that people thought were one value turn into 7 values.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `as.POSIXlt` which converts a numeric data type to the (possibly) fractional number of days that have passed since an origin date, which is why it is important to know which date is counted as day 1 (or sometimes day 0!) by whatever generated your data:

```
x <- 1269576000000
# Guessing at the origin
as.POSIXlt( x/1e3, tz="GMT", origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2010-03-26 04:00:00 GMT"
```

And to display fractional seconds, set the option `digits.secs`, i.e.

```
options(digits.secs=3)
x <- 1269576000500
as.POSIXlt( x/1e3, tz="GMT", origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2010-03-26 04:00:00.5 GMT"
```

Which can easily be added to a dataframe (I am not sure why @DWin thinks this is a problem):

```
x <- 1269576000000
x <- seq( x , by = 500 , length.out = 10 )
df <- data.frame( ID = 1:10 , Time = as.POSIXlt( x/1e3, tz="GMT", origin="1970-01-01") )
df
   ID                  Time
1   1 2010-03-26 04:00:00.0
2   2 2010-03-26 04:00:00.5
3   3 2010-03-26 04:00:01.0
4   4 2010-03-26 04:00:01.5
5   5 2010-03-26 04:00:02.0
6   6 2010-03-26 04:00:02.5
7   7 2010-03-26 04:00:03.0
8   8 2010-03-26 04:00:03.5
9   9 2010-03-26 04:00:04.0
10 10 2010-03-26 04:00:04.5
```

Comment: It's not the fraction number of days. That's Excel.

Comment: @DWin ok, sloppy use of terminology, its the number of seconds, which can represent a fractional number of days.

Comment: It's only the fractional number of days if that fraction happens to be `1/(24*3600)`